# Activating jbimages plugin causes TinyMCE fail to load

Tags: javascript, plugins, tinymce

I'm trying to add [jbimages](http://justboil.me/tinymce-images-plugin/) plugin to `TinyMCE`.
When I add `,jbimages` to `plugins:` line of `TinyMCE` configuration, `TinyMCE` fails to load and gives this error in FireBug's console:

```
TypeError: this.getDoc() is undefined
http://localhost/proj/client/js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js
Line 1
```

my `TinyMCE` configuration that fails is this:

```
tinyMCE.init({
    // General options
    mode : "exact",
        elements : "question",
    theme : "advanced",
    plugins : "autolink,lists,pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template,wordcount,advlist,visualblocks,jbimages",

    // Theme options
    theme_advanced_buttons1 : "bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|,ltr,rtl,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
    theme_advanced_buttons2 : "search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,cleanup,code,|,insertdate,inserttime,preview,|,forecolor,backcolor",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
    theme_advanced_resizing : true,
    language : 'fa',
        directionality : "rtl",

    // Drop lists for link/image/media/template bloglists
    template_external_list_url : "lists/template_list.js",
    external_link_list_url : "lists/link_list.js",
    external_image_list_url : "lists/image_list.js",
    media_external_list_url : "lists/media_list.js",
    relative_urls:false,
    // Replace values for the template plugin
    template_replace_values : {
        username : "Some User",
        staffid : "991234"
    }
});
```

What is the problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.
The issue is that I'm using the `language` option in `TinyMCE` and `jbimages` tries to load language files that don't exist.
I created the required language files for `jbimages` according to [this](http://justboil.me/tinymce-images-plugin/translating-to-other-languages/) and the problem was solved.